# Grails - adding Maven dependency to Eclipse classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, grails

I've added a Maven dependency into my Grails project, and I'm trying to get that reflected on my Eclipse setup. I've already run `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` and `grails refresh-dependencies` (I don't know the difference) but neither got the job done. There are no errors, and I can see that the dependency is correctly reported in `grails dependency-report`.

Comment: does it have other maven specified dependencies or just this one is missing ?

Comment: Well, it has transitive dependencies, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the difference is, but after running `refresh-dependencies` using GGTS in Eclipse [project context ("right click") > Grails Tools > Refresh Dependencies], the jars appeared in the classpath.